# Please help me write a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need to find the `news` items from `news table` and the `number of comments` for each news item from `comments table`. I need this in a single array/resultset... the tables are linked by `news.id=news_comments.news_id`. Any help?

Comment: my dear your table sturcutrs? describe table structures of both tables

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please add the `homework` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  news.id,
        COUNT(comments.news_id) TotalComments
FROM    news LEFT JOIN
        comments    ON  news.id=news_comments.news_id
GROUP BY    news.id
```

If you use a left join, the result set will also return all news articles with no comments, where as if you use an inner join, these articles will be excluded from your result set.

Comment: @zerkms, just a comment I wanted to post on your answer. I would realy not recomend storing the count in the news table. This is not a good practice, as the value can be very easily calculated. Also, if there was to be any filter on the comments (lets say between dates) this number/field would be useless.

Comment: "very easy" to use, but not to execute. The execution plan for this query will be terrible. Once you'll need to get "the most 10 commented news" of 10M news and 100B comments - you'll get a reeeeeeeally big trouble. Whereas task "between dates" is very rare and can be performed in the way you offered.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should check out some tutorials, or buy a book on learning SQL:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_join_inner.asp

The things you need to look into are how to take a count, and how to do an inner join.  This is a fairly basic query, so you shouldn't have any problems once you work up to it.

If you get stuck on a particular part, let us know, show us what you've got so far, and maybe we can provide more specific help.